# With Docker, which directories are impacted by disk I/O

Tags: docker

I want to mount a TMPFS ( ramdrive ) prior to install docker so that I can measure performance benefits.

On my previous tests it appeared that IOWAIT was a little higher with Docker, so I uninstalled Docker, mounted the /var/lib/docker to a 3GB ramdisk (TMPFS ) and ran again my tests. The results were better, but just slightly.

Am I missing any other directories that are under intense Disk I/O when operating a Docker Container ?

Comment: Docker shouldn't touch anything outside of /var/lib/docker. What kind of tests are you doing?